# JavaScript fails after refreshing in only Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

After 1-3 refreshes of my webpage my JavaScript stops working, all other browsers are fine. This sounds like an issue with Chrome itself but is there anyway I can fix it from the website side?

website: http://fenlig.com/liveplayers.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
        $('#playerstats').load('php/players.php')
        }, 100);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Works fine for me (Chrome 28.0.1500.71). Just a note: consider using long polling or sockets instead of AJAX requests every 0.1s

Comment: I can reproduce this with Chrome 28.0.1500.71 on Mac OS X. But I would reduce the polling frequency like Konrad suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Here is excerpt from your page:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{    
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
    $('#time').load('php/uptime.php')
    }, 1000);
});
</script>

<!-- Javascript -->

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
        $('#playerstats').load('php/players.php')
        }, 100);
    });
    </script>
```

I'm surprised it works in other browsers, frankly. You should use `$(document).ready()` only once:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{    
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
    $('#time').load('php/uptime.php')
    }, 1000);
    var refreshId1 = setInterval(function()
        {
        $('#playerstats').load('php/players.php')
        }, 100);
});
```

Comment: And yes, you will bomb your server to death with such scripts, if number of users will be high enough.

Comment: There is absolute no problem with having more than one `document.ready` (besides maintainability) in a single file.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm still quite new as you may have guessed. I've cleaned it up a good bit and removed the double document.ready part.

Comment: @Andreas Obviously, in some browsers (or at least in some builds of them) there IS a problem. And me and OP clearly saw it.

Comment: @SimonKay now it shows 2 players, or whatever it is: > Player Stats
Online Players
Liber8or

Offline Players
Fenlig
Server